# How to choose a valid window of the signal in STFT

Tags: signal-processing, fft, wavelet, haar-wavelet

I have been reading a tutorial about `short time fourier transfor`, and i reached some lines in the text which i could not understand or figure out. the tutorial says the following

```
This window function is first located to the very beginning of the signal. That is, the   
window function is located at t=0. Let's suppose that the width of the window is "T" s. At 
this time instant (t=0), the window function will overlap with the first T/2 seconds (I  
will assume that all time units are in seconds). The window function and the signal are 
then multiplied. By doing this, only the first T/2 seconds of the signal is being chosen, 
with the appropriate weighting of the window.
```

What i could not understand is: `only the first T/2 seconds of the signal is being chosen, 
    with the appropriate weighting of the window`.

my question is: why only the first T/2 seconds will be chosen? I think, since the width of the window is T, then the whole portion of the signal contained within the width of the window should be chosen, and NOT only the T/2 of the window.

Can any one please explain why T/2 of the width of thw window is chosen instead of T?

Answer (score 0):

For high precission analysis of time-series one needs to apply a window like `Hanning-Window` or `Hamming-Window` to a short interval of the time-series before calculating the FFT to avoid *leakage* or *side-lobes* or whatever you may call the effect of the rectangular window which is used implicitely if no other window is applied.

For a complete analysis this window is moved by about 50% of the window length between consecutive FFTs. (The exact optimal shift depends on the window, 50% is a good value)

So with a window length of 100ms you will start the window at 200ms, 250ms, 300ms, ...

Now about the **start** of your time series. In order to see the very beginning of your time-series in the FFTs, you need to zero-pad the signal **before** it begins and start the first window at -50ms. Then you continue with 0ms, 50ms, 100ms, and so on.

You see the very first window start half a window-length **before** the actual time-series starts. (I guess this is meant in your text with T/2)